# How to embed Grafana panel into web application with security?

Tags: security, iframe, grafana, okta

1. We have enabled SSO between web application and Grafana using Okta and embedded Iframes into web application, But embedded iframes are not rendering graphs. Okta not able to set cookie through iframe.
2. We enabled iframe embedding from Okta to solve the issue. But it does not work.
3. From a community discussion one suggested to set a security.cookie_samesite to none from Grafana. But after setting the cookie to none, SSO stopped working.

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3752

4. We have tried auth proxy. From documentation it is not clear on how to set the header when we do SSO, and also not clear on how to verify the header from Grafana.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/auth-proxy/

some one already solved this issue?

Comment: You app, which is embeding Grafana must initialize SSO session/authentication. Grafana's iframe then just reuse that SSO session. Of course Grafana must have enabled embeding as well.